# DataGrid UI virtualization

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, virtualization

i have a DataGrid. And a bind a List<> to it and add at runtime in the code a few columns. After adding this columns the vertical scrolling isn't very good. The added columns in code are dynamic created, i think between 10 - 50. And there are about 140 rows. How can i fix it?

I read something about ui virtualization, but i dont understand how use it on a DataGrid?
Can someone help me to finde a solution?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You need a datagrid that supports UI virtualization for columns. I don't believe the free Microsoft Silverlight datagrid supports that.

Not sure if there's a solution for that, but I do want to point out that we sell a datagrid for Silverlight at Xceed that supports it.

**Link to this solution:** http://xceed.com/grid_silverlight_intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but i dont want buy one... can i build a own UI virtualization for columns ?

Comment: No problem. I don't know if you can retrofit this capability in that datagrid, haven't tried. Time is money...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of each individual column, and you can also set some columns to occupy the remaining available space, example:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```